# Serialization does not work with a custom linked list

Tags: java, serialization, io, try-catch, singly-linked-list

So here is my problem:
for a project I had to create a custom linked list whereby I had to add nodes to it and save/load it to and from the disk using serialisation
here are some things about my system before I define the problem

- I have a generic 'customer file' which acts as the node data
- this is stored in a node object which acts as an element of the list
- there is a customer file class where the information such as name and email address are stored as well as the various get and set methods for each - these work fine
- there is a node class with get and set data and next methods for each whereby the next item is a node object and acts as the next item in the list
- there is a singly linked class with add, remove, modify, sort, search etc... methods - IT IS A CUSTOM MADE CLASS AND SO DOES NOT IMPLEMENT ANY JAVA PREMADE LISTS.
- a lot of testing has been on all classes separately and used together - these methods are foolproof - they work
- there is a main class which is used for the main interface between the user and the system - it is a CLI system (command line)
- it has a save list to file function and load list from file function (in the main class) whereby each function uses serialization or deserialization to save/load the list from the disk
- all classes implement the serializable interface
- there is a 'MAIN' method in the main class whereby a while loop operates which allows the user to modify the list in some way (eg add a record, remove a record etc...)
- the list is loaded outside the loop so it is not cleared each time the loop iterates (a common problem amongst colleagues)
- i have a password for the system whereby identical methods are used to save a string to another file location and that has worked for weeks - the password is saved at that location and can be accessed, changed and removed at will
- these load/save methods have the appropriate try/catch methods to catch any exceptions

The problem is that each time i load up my programming environment and want to look at the list, I find that the list on file is 'empty' and contained no records from when i last added/removed stuff.

I add records and modify the list - easy peasy as the other classes work - once these are added, i call the print function which simply displays all items in the list and it is fine.

However, the minute i close the environment, they are lost and when i reopen the environment to look at the list again, it is empty!

Upon looking in the folder where these classes are saved, i have noticed each time i run the program that 'shells' are created and remain there until the program is closed/finished however the 'listData.ser' which should have the linked list saved does not have any data.

Likewise the password file contains the password which was saved fine - so i am a little confused as to why my code does not work.

Here is my save list method:

```
private static void saveListToFile(SinglyLinkedList lst) {
    try {
        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("ListData.ser"));
        os.writeObject(lst);
        os.flush();
        os.close();
    } 

    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Likewise the load list method is similar but uses object input stream and file input stream.

Any suggestions?

P.S. My main while loop is over 400 lines of code long and therefore not feasible to post.

Update 1.
Deserialization code in load list method:

```
private static SinglyLinkedList loadListFromFile() {
    SinglyLinkedList lst = null;

    try {
        ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("ListData.ser"));
        lst = (SinglyLinkedList) is.readObject();
        is.close();
    }

    catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return lst;
}
```

I dont think the singly linked list class itself is the problem (response to comment) and it is not feasible to copy as it is also over 300 lines of code (lots of methods).

Comment: Can you post your `SinglyLinkedList` code?  Looks like you're using `ObjectOutputStream` correctly, but it's hard to tell what the serialization problem is without being able to see the code of what's being serialized.

Comment: how you are deserializing it? post any code if you can

Comment: @BenLawry i cannot upload this as the code is too large, but the singly linked list works - I have test classes which specifically test each method and they work fine - debugging determined that the function of the singly linked list in itself is fine - the problem lies in saving it

Comment: @Arpit see updated problem above for this

Comment: @Lukeg101 the problem MUST be somewhere in `SinglyLinkedList` because that class' definition controls how instances of it get Serialized - whether the methods work or not is almost completely irrelevant to serialization.  Sounds like perhaps some of the fields in that class are marked `transient` or something important is getting nulled out before you write the object, unless you're seeing stack traces get printed.  There are other possibilities, but I'm afraid it's a bit of a wild goose chase without some code to look at.

Comment: @BenLawry the singly linked list is a custom built one - that is it does not use standard java classes. the singly linked list implements a serializable interface

Comment: @Lukeg101 whether SLL is part of the JRE/JDK isn't important.  Serialization works the same way for all classes whether those classes are built-in or custom-defined.  By implementing `Serializable`, you're giving the JVM permission to traverse SLL's object hierarchy and write all non-transient instance variables to disk.  If you want different behavior, you must override `writeObject(ObjectOutputStream)` and `readObject(ObjectInputStream)` methods correctly.  This is a feature of the Java language and doesn't change whether you "use standard java classes" or not.

Comment: That code is correct . now only one option left that is your list code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling `close()` on the `FileOutputStream` when you are done writing the file/object?

Comment: The `FileOutputStream` should be closed with the call to `os.close()`, no?

Comment: Sometimes the first step in debugging is to make sure that all the "this should happen when I do this" stuff is explicit :)

Comment: each time the list is saved - the save list method is  called to do so (see above) and that code uses close() and flush() so Im pretty sure this is not the problem. Also I have password methods to save the password to another file which are more or less identical (it saves a string and not a singly linked list object) good suggestion though

Comment: @mattb i have debugged the singly linked list, the customer file and node classes - they work fine. the problem lies i the IO of the main class, whereby each time the programming environment is opened - the list itself is empty

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it, instead of posting my code I tried to do it myself. I turns out there were a few static methods of the list class - these were changed to non-static and now the list saves as expected each time.
Thanks for the help